# Updating the $scope value

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I wanted to display the added users dynamically in the dashboard.
My code is in the following way.
Controller: where the actual action triggers .
Adding the user function

```
$scope.addUser= function(){
    modalService.addUser();
}

function init(){
   // Someother functions
   getUserRequests()
};

function getUserRequests() {
    datacontext.getExtranetUserRequests()
        .then(function (data){
            vm.ExtranetUserRequest = data;
        });
};
```

Service: modalService

```
addUser: function (column) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       templateUrl: 'app/NewExtranetSite/Popup/userModal.html',
                controller: 'userModal',
       });

updateUser: function(){
    // updates the user
});
```

Controller :userModal 
In the userModal.html after adding the info and on clicking save, add user function will be triggered.

```
function addUser(){
    datacontext.saveNewExtranetuserRequest($scope.user);
};
```

I would like to initiate the getUserRequests() after the completion of add user in the user modal

So that the newly added user can be visble on the dashboard without refreshing the page

Comment: please format code properly..its hard to understand.

Comment: The copy paste is so very bad in this question, impossible to format because of missing brackets, contents... etc...

Answer (score 0):

The $modal.open function returns a promise, so it's easy to wait for the modal to close and then execute another function. Let 'addUser' return this promise, then wait for it to finish before executing getUserRequests:

in modalService:

```
addUser: function (column) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/NewExtranetSite/Popup/userModal.html',
        controller: 'userModal',
    });
    return modalInstance;
}
```

in controller:

```
$scope.addUser= function(){
    modalService.addUser().then((resultReturnedFromModal) => {
        getUserRequests();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer u shortly.

1. You have a view where you are adding user details from input using one form ().
2. On ng-submit or ng-click action you can call one method in your that particular view's controller.
3. Now to display user details, you might know json. So create a blank $scope variable which will contain added user details.($scope.variable=[];)
4. Now on submit just hit **

> $sope.variable.push({'key':value,'value':value});

**
once your object is populated with new data it will automatically displayed in the view.
5. We have just awesome ng-repeat angular's directive to show dynamical list containing objects.
6. **

> ng-repeat="key in variable track by $index"

**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad post.

Let me explain briefly in this post

I would like to display the added data dynamically on the page.
I have a controller where the user addition action takes place.

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'newUser';

angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,

    ['modalService', '$scope', 'dataContext', newUser]);

function newUser(modalService, $scope, dataContext) {

    init();


    function init() {

        var extranetSiteRequestId = +$routeParams.id;
        if (extranetSiteRequestId && extranetSiteRequestId > 0) {
            getItem(extranetSiteRequestId);
            getUserRequests();

        }


    }
    $scope.newuserRequest = function () {


        modalService.addUser();

    }

    function getUserRequests() {
        datacontext.getExtranetUserRequests().then(function (data) {
            vm.UserData = data;
        });

    };
    }
}());
```

I am using a service modalService to handle the add user request.

```
(function (){
    'use strict';

    var serviceId = 'modalService'

    angular.module('app').service(serviceId, ['$modal', modalService]);

    function modalService($modal) {

        return {


            addUser: function () {


                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'app/NewExtranetSite/Popup/userModal.html',
                    controller: 'userModal',



                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function (userDetails) {
                    if (userDetails) {
                        alert(userDetails) ;
                    };
                })






                },
        };
    }
})();
```

finally in the userModal controller am handling the new user added request

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'userModal';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'datacontext', 'common', addUserModalFunction]);

    function addUserModalFunction($scope, $modalInstance, datacontext, common) {

        var vm = $scope;

        vm.cancel = cancel;

        vm.submit = addUser;

        init();



        function init() {
            common.logger.log("controller loaded", null, controllerId);
            common.activateController([], controllerId);
        }
        function cancel() {
            $modalInstance.close();

        }
        $scope.open = function ($event, opened) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope[opened] = true;
        };

        function addUser() {

            datacontext.saveNewExtranetuserRequest($scope.user).then(function(data){
                $modalInstance.close($scope.user);
                });
            };




    };








})();
```

Now the problem is I would like to add a success or then function in the ***newUser*** Controller after the modalService.adduser complete

EX:  modalService.addUser().then(function(results){

```
            });
```

Fikkatra Thanks for the reply but couldn't able to achieve

am very bad @ angular